# how to print a tree in order by using stack and depth first search?

Tags: java, depth-first-search

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Node {
public int iData; // data item (key)
public double dData; // data item
public Node leftChild; // this node's left child
public Node rightChild; // this node's right child
public int level;
public boolean flag;

public void displayNode() // display ourself
{
    System.out.print('{');
    System.out.print(level);
    System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(iData);
    System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(dData);
    System.out.print("} ");
    System.out.println(" ");
}
} // end class Node
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Tree {
private Node root; // first node of tree

// -------------------------------------------------------------
public Tree() // constructor
{
root = null;
} // no nodes in tree yet
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void insert(int id, double dd) {
Node newNode = new Node(); // make new node
newNode.iData = id; // insert data
newNode.dData = dd;
if (root == null) // no node in root
    root = newNode;
else // root occupied
{
    Node current = root; // start at root
    Node parent;
    while (true) // (exits internally)
    {
        parent = current;
        if (id < current.iData) // go left?
        {
            current = current.leftChild;
            if (current == null) // if end of the line,
            { // insert on left
                parent.leftChild = newNode;
                return;
            }
        } // end if go left
        else // or go right?
        {
            current = current.rightChild;
            if (current == null) // if end of the line
            { // insert on right
                parent.rightChild = newNode;
                return;
            }
        } // end else go right
    } // end while
} // end else not root
} // end insert()
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void breadthFirstDisplay() {
    Queue newQueue = new LinkedList();
    int level = 0;
    newQueue.add(root);
    int temp = root.iData;
    while (!newQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Node theNode = (Node) newQueue.remove();
        if (temp > theNode.iData)
            level++;
        theNode.level = level;
        theNode.displayNode();
        temp = theNode.iData;
        if (theNode.leftChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.leftChild);
        }
        if (theNode.rightChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.rightChild);
        }
    }
}

public void depthFirstStackDisplay() {

}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class Tree
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class TreeApp {
public static void main(String[] args){
Tree theTree = new Tree();

theTree.insert(5, 1.5);
theTree.insert(4, 1.2);
theTree.insert(6, 1.7);
theTree.insert(9, 1.5);
theTree.insert(1, 1.2);
theTree.insert(2, 1.7);
theTree.insert(3, 1.5);
theTree.insert(7, 1.2);
theTree.insert(8, 1.7);

theTree.breadthFirstDisplay();
theTree.depthFirstStackDisplay();

}// -------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class TreeApp
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I want to write a function by depth first search
so that the output is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Boolean flag is set in class Node and the i want that the function is similar to breadth first search.

I can't find relevant source to help me to complete it.

Comment: What did you try to do? You can find pseudo code of depth-first search [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: "Depth first" means you *recursively* call the 'depthfirst' routine itself on all Left nodes, then on all Right nodes. You also need to pass your stack.

Comment: @Jongware no, stackbased needs no recursion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_2 shows both stack and recursion based approaches.

Comment: @zapl: you're right! I always use recursion 'cause it's easier (trvial) to implement, but next time I'll take a look at iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this alogo to print depth first traversal (inorder traversal according to your problem ).It will use stack.

1) Create an empty stack S.

2) Initialize current node as root

3) Push the current node to S and set current = current->left until current is NULL

4) If current is NULL and stack is not empty then

```
 a) Pop the top item from stack.

 b) Print the popped item, set current = popped_item->right 

 c) Go to step 3.
```

5) If current is NULL and stack is empty then we are done.

I don't know much about java but you can take the help of this c code :

```
    /* Iterative function for inorder tree traversal */
void inOrder(struct Node *root)
{
  /* set current to root of binary tree */
  struct Node *current = root;
  struct sNode *s = NULL;  /* Initialize stack s */
  bool done = 0;

  while (!done)
  {
    /* Reach the left most Node of the current Node */
    if(current !=  NULL)
    {
      /* place pointer to a tree node on the stack before traversing
        the node's left subtree */
      push(&s, current);                                              
      current = current->leftChild; 
    }

    /* backtrack from the empty subtree and visit the Node
       at the top of the stack; however, if the stack is empty,
      you are done */
    else                                                             
    {
      if (!isEmpty(s))
      {
        current = pop(&s);
        printf("%d ", current->idata);

        /* we have visited the node and its left subtree.
          Now, it's right subtree's turn */
        current = current->rightChild;
      }
      else
        done = 1;
    }
  } /* end of while */ 
}
```